# Moving the mouse based on the color

Tags: opencv

I am making a program with OpenCV C++ that when it detects the blue color it just move the mouse to the new position of the blue object.

What i did in steps is

1. Transforming from BGR to HSV
2. Using InRange to just get the blue range
3. Finding the Contours with the biggest area to detect the object
4. taking the position of last point in the contour and make it the new mouse position so that as the object moves , the mouse also moves.

The problem with this is that when i fix the position of the object, the contours points is changed so the cursor moves away from the position with +-10 and go back and so on so that seems annoying so anybody has a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue brought me here, so I try to help even it's an old question. If I understand, the problem is that when the object don't move, the pointer slightly move because the contour is not fixed, but change a little bit continuously. If this it the case you should take the centroid of the countour, not the last point, this should be more stable.